# How can I search within hidden files and folders in Windows 7/8?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8

How can I search in hidden files and folders in windows 7 and 8?

Comment: Are there files that don't show up when you search for them or you want specificity to your search criteria for hidden files/folders only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open your "Computer" icon (either from the Start menu or Desktop icon) and click on the "Organize" menu from your menu ribbon (should be the first one) then select the "Folder and Search Option". From there select the "View" tab then look for the "Hidden Files and Folders" menu then select the "Show Hidden files, folder and drives." radio-button.

Answer (score 5):

In Win 8 - open the File Explorer and select the View tab, on the right side select the "Options" to bring up the Folders Options box (if you use the menu down arrow on "Options", then select "change folders and search options") then select the "Search" tab. 
Under the "How to Search" section, check the box next to "Don't use the index when searching in the file folders for system files"(searches may take a little longer - but you get the desired results!)  Very annoying Microsoft! This worked for me, hope it helps for you also !!

Answer (score 0):

Just click the search box at upper right hand and you will see options for searching by size. You can choose tiny

Comment: The question is about hidden files/folders, it has nothing to do with size.